# How do I create such a dynamic structure?HTML + PHP

Tags: php, html

**I have the following PHP code, which dynamically generates content:**

```
<div id="carousel-example" class="carousel slide hidden-xs" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
            <div class="row">
                <?php foreach ($this->getItems() as $_item): ?>
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <a class="product-image" href="<?php echo $_item->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?>"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_item, 'thumbnail')->resize(75); ?>" width="75" height="75" alt="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?>" /></a>
                        <div class="product-details">
                            <h3 class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_item->getProductUrl() ?>"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?></a></h3>
                            <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_item, true) ?>
                            <button type="button" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Add to Cart')) ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_item) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button>
                            <ul class="add-to-links">
                                <?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow()) : ?>
                                     <li><a href="<?php echo $this->getAddToWishlistUrl($_item) ?>" class="link-wishlist"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?></a></li>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                                <?php if($_compareUrl=$this->getAddToCompareUrl($_item)): ?>
                                    <li><span class="separator">|</span> <a href="<?php echo $_compareUrl ?>" class="link-compare"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Compare') ?></a></li>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**The above code outputs the following structure:**

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3">product1</div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">product2</div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">product3</div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">product4</div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">product5</div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">product6</div>
            .
            .
            .
            etc..
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**I want to create this structure:**

```
 <div class="carousel-inner">
     <div class="item active">
         <div class="row">
             <div class="col-sm-3">product1</div>
             <div class="col-sm-3">product2</div>
             <div class="col-sm-3">product3</div>
             <div class="col-sm-3">product4</div>
         </div>
     </div>

     <div class="item">
         <div class="row">
             <div class="col-sm-3">product1</div>
             <div class="col-sm-3">product2</div>
             <div class="col-sm-3">product3</div>
             <div class="col-sm-3">product4</div>
         </div>
     </div>

     <div class="item">
         <div class="row">
             <div class="col-sm-3">product1</div>
             <div class="col-sm-3">product2</div>
             <div class="col-sm-3">product3</div>
             <div class="col-sm-3">product4</div>
         </div>
     </div>
     .
     .
     .
     etc...
</div>
```

How do I change the dynamic structure so they get what they want?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In order to create the structure you want**:

- You need to put **`<div class="item active">`** in the **`foreach`** loop as well, because in order to have many **`items`**, **you want that to be repeated many times too**.
- You have to remove **`active`** from **`<div class="item active">`** as it will be added to every **`item`**, while **we only want it to be in the first one**.
- You have to create a checking variable, so that the class **`active`** is added to the first **`item`** only.

**Your final code should look like**:

```
<div id="carousel-example" class="carousel slide hidden-xs" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <?php
            $i = 0; /* This is the checking variable */
            $active; /* This is the variable containing the class 'active' */
            foreach ($this->getItems() as $_item):
                $i++; /* We increment the checking variable in each loop */
                $active = ($i === 1) ? "active" : ""; /* We make the check */
        ?>
                <div class="item <?php echo $active;?>">
                    <!-- The rest of your code as it is -->
                </div>
        <?php
            endforeach;
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

**[EDIT]:**

Considering your comment, in the case of wanting four products in each item, you would need to use another **`loop`** inside **`<div class = "row">`**.

The key part you are doing wrong in your code, however, that doesn't change, is that **you don't loop the `<div class = "item">` and that's way you have only one**.

A preview of how your code inside **`<div class="item">`** should be:

```
<div class="item <?php echo $active;?>">
    <div class="row">
        <?php
            for ($i = 0; $i <= 4; ++$i):
        ?>
                <div class="col-sm-3"><!-- The rest of the code --></div>
        <?php
            endfor;
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the problem is that your example is something like   <div class="item active">product1</div>

Comment: I want a container ordered 4 produse..asa as in my example above

Comment: Then you need two **`foreach`** loops. One used to create multiple items and another one to create four products in each item. The key part you are doing wrong is that you don't loop the item and that's way you have only one.

Comment: please can you fill your example to see exactly what you mean?

Comment: @JohnSmith I filled it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div id="carousel-example" class="carousel slide hidden-xs" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
            <div class="row">
            <?php foreach ($this->getItems() as $key=>$_item): // add $key in for loop
                if($key != 0 && $key % 4 == 0) { // just add this code - it will check if 4 records has been displayed re create row div...
                    echo '</div><div class="row">';
                }
            ?>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <a class="product-image" href="<?php echo $_item->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?>"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_item, 'thumbnail')->resize(75); ?>" width="75" height="75" alt="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?>" /></a>
                    <div class="product-details">
                        <h3 class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_item->getProductUrl() ?>"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?></a></h3>
                        <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_item, true) ?>
                        <button type="button" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Add to Cart')) ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_item) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button>
                        <ul class="add-to-links">
                            <?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow()) : ?>
                                <li><a href="<?php echo $this->getAddToWishlistUrl($_item) ?>" class="link-wishlist"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?></a></li>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                            <?php if($_compareUrl=$this->getAddToCompareUrl($_item)): ?>
                                <li><span class="separator">|</span> <a href="<?php echo $_compareUrl ?>" class="link-compare"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Compare') ?></a></li>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```